# Concatenating a date field to a drop-down based time field

Tags: date-time

I am trying to create Start Date/Time and End Date/Time fields. Here are my parameters:

Start Date
STime (drop down)
End Date
ETime (drop down)
Start Date/Time (calculated)
 =concat(substring-before(Start Date, "T"), "T", substring-after(STime, "T"))
End Date/Time (calculated)
 =concat(substring-before(End Date, "T"), "T", substring-after(ETime, "T"))

All the above are set into Date and Time data type and I can't seem to make it work. The reason why I had to create a separate field for the time is because I want to make it convenient for the user to put the time by just choosing from a drop down box instead of making them manually type the time.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint online? and STime Dropdown has what type of values? Also, add what sample expected outcome after the concat

Answer (score 0):

Try [Moment.JS](https://momentjs.com/) for all your date / time needs. It's brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple form that to demonstrate, this is a simple solution that works smoothly.

The start and end date are Date picker fields,

The Start and end times are drop down lists with manually entered times, for example "01:00"

I have created a text box underneath that has a concat function to combine the two, this could be edite to make it look cleaner, but the practicality is there.

Hope this helps,

[image]